# How to bind a Date column aggregate it with multiple columns in R

Tags: r, database, aggregate, cbind

There is a data frame with nearly 10 columns. 
There is a column called "week" and it contains dates(with multiple entries for a single date) and I need to bind it and aggregate with other three columns respectively. 
How can I do that in a single step in R?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Comment: See also [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).